# Control OS Mouse Event using Windows Form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, mouseevent

The program I am trying to do is to simulate the mouse event of a operating system using keyboard with Windows Form. Right now I am able to change the cursor and do different actions like mouse clicking inside the Form (when the Form is on the Top).

The problem is I would like to extend it to the whole Operating System, which means even if my Windows Form is not at the top, I am still able to control my cursor and do all sorts of mouse event on other applications while the Form is running. How should I do to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can synthesize OS-wide keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks using the Win32 [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) API. You can call it from C# using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx). Sample code can be found here: [SendInput on PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html).

I remember back in the day I used the SendInput (and a screenshot API) to create a Minesweeper bot in C# (2.0 I think). It could solve an Expert puzzle in about one second. I wish I still had the source code to sample here, but I don't.

**EDIT:** It appears someone has already created a nice .NET warpper for the `SendInput()`: [Windows Input Simulator on CodePlex](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I am focusing on another stuff right now, but this might help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this library [Global System Hooks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET) which uses global system hooks to detect all mouse and keyboard events include those outside of your application.

Comment: He's looking for a way to simulate keystrokes, not listen to them.